# How to stretch image based on right side?

Tags: html, css

I have this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18752/ I want that image height is based on right side so that image always goes to the end of div. Any suggestion?

```
<div class="blog_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="blog_image">
                <img src="img/property_img.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="blog_details">
                <div class="blog_title">This comfortable apartment is located in the heart of Zurich</div>
                <div class="blog_posted">POSTED ON: <span>JANUARY 24 2016 14:35h </span>IN <span>KREIS 1</span></div>
                    <p class="blog_more-details">
                    Wheather a single room studio or multi-room apartment, each has at least one own bathroom and a fully quipped kitches.
                    </p>
                <div class="sold_by">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 ">
                                    <div class="profile-image"><img src="img/profile.png" /></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 no-padding-left">
                    <span class="property">ARTICLE WRITEN BY</span>
                    <span class="property_name">Janine Lindenmuller</span>
                    <div class="blog_read_more">
                    <a href="#">READ MORE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Wow, how many divs can one use... /offtopic

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to remove bootstrap grid class and have to write some custom css with `display:table-cell`

for example

```
.img,.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.img {
  width:60%;
}
.text {
  width:40%;
}
```

Also use low dimension image. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18754/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your image row like this:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/sLjL37e2/)**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```